# Can't stop and delete Google Cloud TPU (Cloud TPU received a bad request. Please use Cloud TPU API with V2 versions.)

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, google-cloud-tpu

I'm trying to stop and delete a TPU node, but I'm getting the following error: `Failed to stop gpt-alignment: Cloud TPU received a bad request. Please use Cloud TPU API with V2 versions. [EID: 0xb96542536c043d]`.

I tried using the Google Cloud Platform website to stop it and got that message.

And I get the following messagewhen I run `gcloud compute instances stop gpt-alignment --zone=europe-west4-a` in the command line: `ERROR: (gcloud.compute.instances.stop) HTTPError 404: The resource 'projects/gpt-alignment/zones/europe-west4-a/instances/gpt-alignment' was not found`.

Do I just need to wait it out or is there something I am missing? I've read that sometimes it just takes a while to remove it, but I'm not sure that's the case here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try accessing it through the CLI with: [`gcloud compute tpus`](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/compute/tpus)`tpu-vm list`.

So this should be:

```
gcloud compute tpus stop gpt-alignment --zone=europe-west4-a
gcloud compute tpus delete gpt-alignment --zone=europe-west4-a
```

I'd assume that `ctpu` is the V1 API and `gcloud compute tpus` is the V2 API.

Comment: If I run `gcloud compute tpus list --zone=europe-west4-a`, I get:  `gpt-alignment  europe-west4-a  v3-8   default  10.164.0.0/20  READY`. (Same thing with `gcloud compute tpus tpu-vm list --zone=europe-west4-a`)

Comment: Ah, I just now ended up doing the same thing as your edit and it worked! Thanks!

Weird how the website doesn't just automatically try either V1 or V2 though.

Comment: `instances != tpus` ...you've tried shutting down a VM, not a TPU... while the web console seems to have a bug, which you could report, in case you care. This may eventually even still work with TPU deployed with the V1 API; doesn't seem to be fully migrated yet.

Comment: Ah ok, I guess I just assumed that the instances just includes tpus with it. Makes sense.